# Regex para capturar bloco de texto

Tags: c#, regex

Preciso extrair blocos de texto que estão dentro de #regions:

```
#region VARIAVEIS GLOBAIS
string aux1 = "teste";
string aux2 = "teste2";
...
#endregion
```

O retorno seria:

```
string aux1 = "teste";
string aux2 = "teste2";
...
```

Como faço isso com RegEx?

*Lembrando que cada region apresenta um nome diferente.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sou desenvolvedor C# mas esta expressão regular resolve esse problema, você precisa ver como ficaria no seu código:

```
(?<=#region VARIAVEIS GLOBAIS).*?(?=#endregion)
```

Exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/wF5pE9/1