# Regex - Expressão Regular para obter um bloco de texto

Tags: delphi, regex

Como seria uma regex para capturar o bloco de variaveis declada em uma unidade delphi ?

O mais proximo que cheguei disso foi usando esta `var[^=]*[^\)];` mas sem sucesso.

```
var
Variavel1 : string;
Variavel2, Variavel3: integer;
Variavel4,
Variavel5 : THandle;

function Soma(a, b: integer): integer;
var
  Varivel1: integer;
  Variavel2, Variavel3: integer;
begin
  //...
end;
```

Qualquer solucao para identificar variaveis é bem vinda.

Comment: O que exatamente você espera de retorno desse bloco de exemplo que você forneceu?

Comment: Somente as variaveis mesmo... seria +- como neste post http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77831/regex-para-capturar-bloco-de-texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não conheço delphi mas pelo que compreendi da logica a região de variáveis se inicia com `var` e termina com alguma outra palavra reservada como `function` ou `begin`.

Usando este conceito pode se fazer uma expressão assim :

```
^var([^~]*?)(function|begin)
```

O conteúdo que vc deseja ficaria no grupo 1, e o grupo 2 seria para especificar términos.

Explicação

- `^var` - deve inicial com "var"
- `([^~]*?)` - grupo 1, capturar qualquer coisa que não seja `~` 0 ou infinitas vezes a menos quantidade possível - usei `~` pois não é muito usado, mas poderia ser algum outro.
- (function|begin) - grupo 2, deve captura a sentença exata, qualquer uma delas.

Seja funcionando no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/mB4nM9/1)

Comment: Gostei da resposta mas esta expressão teria um efeito diferente na versao 2 do regex ?

Comment: @Mutha versão 2? desculpe não entendi. O diferencial da sua é que ele procura o mínimo, e possui um fim definido.

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorancia olhando um material aqui imaginei que existia uma versao 2 para regex.

Comment: Tranquilo, mas que bom que solucionou seu problema :)